# How to list Hosts associated with Ingress

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-java-client

We are using kubernetes java client , https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

to get the information about resources from EKS cluster.
below is the code we are using to list the ingress

```
ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
     Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client); 

    NetworkingV1Api netapi = new NetworkingV1Api();
    V1IngressList list1 = netapi.listIngressForAllNamespaces(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    
    for (V1Ingress item : list1.getItems()) {
        System.out.println("ingress list" + item.getMetadata().getName());
    }
```

Similarly, is there any way OR method to get the list of hosts associated with the ingress ?
I tried searching docs but could not get the info .

Any help / pointers please
Thanks

Comment: An `Ingress` is just a configuration, what do you mean with "hosts associanted" with it?

Comment: @Jonas
Thanks . when we run command kubectl get ingress -A , then it lists the number of ingress and the host URL . 
I want to fetch the HOST URL for each ingress.

basically, there are hostnames (URLs) under the HOST column in the command output . I want that list of those hosts

Comment: Isn't that the part that is configured under `spec.rules.host`? If so: it should be accessible through `item.getSpec().getRules().stream().map(V1IngressRule::getHost).toList();`.

Comment: @Turing85

perfect. Thanks much . I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java API closely mirrors the actual resources definition. If we take a look at the resource definition of an ingress, we can figure it out:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: -registry-ui
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
  - host: PLACEHOLDER
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: -registry-ui
            port:
              name: http
```

(Sample is taken from [one of my `github.com` repos](https://github.com/turing85/k3d-cluster/blob/main/registry-ui/resources/ingress.yml#L12-L31))

We are interested in the value(s) of the `host` field. The path to the resources thus is `spec.rules.[].host`. Notice that `rules` is an array. This will be translated to a `List` in the java client, meaning we will need to have some sort of iteration or reduction over all rules of an ingress.

Now, to translate this to java code, we simply call the corresponding getters:

```
for (V1Ingress item : list1.getItems()) {
    List<String> hosts = item.getSpec().getRules().stream()
            .map(V1IngressRule::getHost)
            .toList();
    System.out.println("Host list" + hosts);
}
```

If we want to get all hosts of all ingresses, we can achieve this through:

```
List<String> hosts = list1.stream()
    .map(V1Ingress::getSpec)
    .map(V1IngressSpec::getRules)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(V1IngressRule::getHost)
    .distinct() // if we want to remove duplicates
    .toList();
```